# Flutter GS-128, CODE-128, EAN-128 barcode reader

Tags: flutter, barcode, barcode-scanner, gs1-ai-syntax

Which the best library in Flutter to read UDIGI 2.0 medical device codes ?
All libraries I use, like: 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';

answers PYTHON-BARCODE+.

Thank you in advance

[image: The image code]

Comment: The question of simply asking for a recommended library, etc. without suggesting what the problem is or the evaluation criteria, may off-topic. Please refer to these help articles to improve your question. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I'm not asking for a recommendation but if I'm doing something wrong since any library I use returns PYTHON-BARCODE+ instead of a number as for other barcodes. This is my for the below library code within setState, please advise.

import 'package:barcode_scan2/model/scan_options.dart';
setState(()  {
   scanResult = ScanResult(
      type: result.type,
      format: result.format,
      rawContent: result.rawContent,
   );
});

Comment: The way you wrote your question just seems to ask for a recommended library. If you have any programming problems, please add more detailed information about the problem you are having, and the minimum source code needed for others to reproduce and investigate the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What you wrote as an answer looks like the type name of the notified data object. Actually, a structured object is notified, and if you look at the details, isn't there a barcode data value somewhere?

Comment: Problem solved since not existent, the barcode tried to read was wrong, even if published as an example. Strange the code read: PYTHON-BARCODE+
Any other code UDI is readable by any library I tried.

Comment: If so, please self-answer that the content of the barcode was the actual read value and did not match what was written as human readble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved since not existent, the barcode tried to read was wrong, even if published as an example. Strange the code read: PYTHON-BARCODE+ Any other code UDI is readable by any library I tried.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

similar problem faced by on using flutter_barcode_scanner package. It gives wrong output for GS1-128 barcode type

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).